# Embed You Tube videos in Android Phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, youtube

Is there any plugin available for Android Phonegap which allows to embed youtube videos in the app itself ? I came across few plugins but most of them uses the Youtube application to play the videos ? I dont want users going out of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this plugin.
[VideoPlayer](https://github.com/raulduran/VideoPlayer)